# Google shows old title, Does anyone have an idea how to change it?

Tags: html, web-crawler, seo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Eeqh.png)When typing in the name of the company, the old title is still shown by search engines.
We couldnt figure out how that happens. The page has been freshly crawled however that tittle is still depicted. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

page: laiqon.com
cms: typo3

The agency that is responsible for building the website couldnt figure out how to change the issue (front and backend).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reasons expressed in the description of the [tag:seo] tag.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set up the Google Search Console. Then you can request re-indexing.

https://search.google.com/search-console/about

Answer (score -1):

Try forcing the site name with `<meta property="og:site_name" content="Laiqon">`. Then request re-indexing, as Jak2k stated.

Answer (score -2):

**Sure, here are some ideas on how to change the title that Google shows for your website:**

1. Make sure that you have updated the title tag on your website. The
   title tag is the HTML element that tells Google what the title of
   your page is. You can  find the title tag in the  section of
   your website's HTML code.
2. Submit your website to Google Search Console. Google Search Console is a free tool that allows you to manage your website's presence in Google Search. You can use Google Search Console to request that Google recrawl your website. This will help to ensure that Google is seeing the updated title tag for your page.
3. Wait for Google to recrawl your website. It can take some time for Google to recrawl your website after you have updated the title tag. You can use the Google Search Console to check the crawl status of your website.
4. Use a 301 redirect. A 301 redirect is a way to tell Google that a page has been moved to a new URL. If you have moved your page to a new URL, you can use a 301 redirect to ensure that Google continues to show the updated title for your page.

**Here are some additional tips for changing the title that Google shows for your website:**

5. Use a clear and concise title that accurately reflects the content of your page.
6. Use keywords that people are likely to search for when they are
   looking for information about your website.
7. Keep the title length to a maximum of 70 characters.
8. Avoid using special characters or symbols in the title.